# Find ad groups where the description is blank

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0

So I have about 5000+ groups and I'm trying to export a CSV of all the ad groups that have a blank description. Tried the following commands but not having much luck and google doesn't seem to know the answer either. Would be easier if I had QAD but doesn't look like that's supported and I don't have the authority to add it. Is there a workaround for it?

```
get-adgroup -filter {description -empty}
get-adgroup -filter {description -like ""}
get-adgroup -filter {description -eq ""}
get-adgroup -filter {description -nolike "*"}
get-adgroup -filter {description -eq null}
```

All these fail, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {-not (description -like "*")}
```

The issue here is that when an AD object has a blank attribute, it's not that it equals null or equals an empty string. The object actually *does not have* that attribute.

So you have to ask for objects where the description does not equal something.